# check expire time for each verification code

Tags: php, laravel

In the code below i check If there is a record for the user Check if ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`exprire_at` is smaller than it is now, it will expire and create a new code, otherwise show the user a message.
But in both cases a new code is created
What is the problem

```
if (Auth::User()->numberVerifies()->where('type','mobile')->exists()) {

           $expiry = optional(Auth::user()->numberVerifies()->where('type','mobile')->select('expire_at')->first())->expire_at;
           if ($expiry < Carbon::now()) {
                    $code = rand(11111, 99999);
                    numVerify::create([
                        'user_id' => Auth::User()->id,
                        'type' => 'mobile',
                        'code' => $code,
                        'expire_at' => Carbon::now()->addSecond(60)
                    ]);
                    
                    session()->flash('messageMobile', 'code created.');

           }
           elseif ($expiry > Carbon::now()) {
              session()->flash('messageMobile', 'you have a code');
           }

       }
```

Comment: Inspect the value of `$expiry`. As long as `Carbon::now()` is greater than zero, both `null` and `false` are "less than" that.

Comment: `What is the problem`...without seeing the content of `$expiry`, there's no way for us to know what's going on. Have you not tried to debug that yourself yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
if ($expiry < Carbon::now()) {
```

to

```
if (!empty($expiry) && $expiry < Carbon::now()) {
```

and

```
} elseif ($expiry > Carbon::now()) {
```

to

```
} else {
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (empty($expiry) || $expiry < Carbon::now()) {`